# Applying each function that repeats individually through each parents children

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to create a simple "slideshow" for thumbnails in a gallery. Each gallery is built up this way with jQuery, HTML and CSS:

```js
var imageGalleries = $("img.work-image").parent().parent();

var loopImages = function(){

    imageGalleries.each(function(){
      var children = $(this).children().children();
      var childrenLength = children.length - 1;
      var i = 0;
      children.each(function(index){
        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
          children.addClass("hide");
          that.removeClass("hide");
          if(childrenLength == index){
            setTimeout(function(){
            setTimeout(loopImages, 0);
            }, 1000);
          }
        }, 1000 * index);
      })
    })
};
loopImages();
```

```css
.hide {
display:none;
}


.work-image {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
  <div class="work-inner" style="height: 248px;">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/animals/thumbs/rights-exempt/mammals/d/domestic-dog_thumb.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/korean-jindo-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1_680-453.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="http://cdn-www.dailypuppy.com/media/dogs/anonymous/patches_maltipoo16.jpg_w450.jpg">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="work-container">
  <div class="work-inner" style="height: 248px;">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/scared-kitten-shutterstock_191443322.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/cat-lying-on-side.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="http://fixnation.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/cats-kittens_00379052.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/live/624_351/images/live/p0/2c/t5/p02ct5b3.jpg">
      <img class="work-image hide" src="http://blog.lifesabundance.com/pics/xbeautiful-whiskery-kitty.jpg.pagespeed.ic.t9JK-YIMfw.jpg">
 </div> 
</div>    


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, each thumbnail container has the class `.work-container` and the inner div has the class `.work-inner`. In `.work-inner`, there are a different amount of images placed (in this case 3 dogs in one and 5 cats in one). The `each` function loops through each images with a `1000ms` delay, hiding all the images by adding the class `.hide` and then removing the class for the image with the current index number.

I want each of the containers to go through all of their images and then restart the loop so that it goes on in infinity. The problem right now is that when the shortest loop ends, it restarts both and not just the specific loop that has ended and just creates this glitch where the "slideshows" restarts to early.

How would I go about getting the loops to only loop themselves individually?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle and share this?

Comment: I created one https://jsfiddle.net/13jmLvyf/

Comment: I made it into a code snippet!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You have complicated the design trying to make the loopImages() to do all the stuff and too many loops and setTimeouts.

If you want to go with less modifications to your code, then I would suggest to make 2 different arrays and call loopImages() twice.

Like

```
var loopImages = function(childeren){
  children.each(function(index){
     var that = $(this);
     setTimeout(function(){
       children.addClass("hide");
       that.removeClass("hide");
       if(childrenLength == index){
         setTimeout(function(){
         setTimeout(loopImages, 0);
         }, 1000);
       }
     }, 1000 * index);
   })
};

var firstImageGallery = $('#firstGallery .work-image');
var secondImageGallery = $('#secondGallery .work-image');

loopImages(firstImageGallery );
loopImages(secondImageGallery );
```

Other options are

1) You can make next element active always and if next element is not present, make the first element as active.
2) You can remove first element and add it to the last. So you can remove loop and in setTimeout always show next element.

Let me know if you need other options.

Try to use less loops and timers for better performance.

Comment: Thank you! I kinda figured that I made it to complicated. I guess that's what stress do to you. :) I could definitely call the function two times, the problem is that this script should be implemented to a Wordpress site. So the galleries are created dynamically. But I guess this can be achieved using your other options?

Comment: Yea, stress is like hell. So if you do not know how many galleries will be there, then you can get galleries and call the loopImages() inside loop. Like var galleries = $('.workimages').parent().parent(); for(galleriesLength){loopImages(childeren)}

Answer (score 1):

I created this quick solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7s5zx5pm/9/

JS:

```
var galleries = $(".work-inner");
var loopImages = function(){

    galleries.each(function(){

        //First round
        $(this).children(".work-image").first().removeClass("hide");
        var self = this;

        var hide_and_display = function(){
            var current_image = $(self).children(".work-image:not(.hide)");
            var next_image = $(current_image).next().removeClass("hide");

            //If next doesn't exist use first
            if(!$(next_image).length){
                $(current_image).addClass("hide");
                $(self).children(".work-image").first().removeClass("hide");
            }

            $(current_image).addClass("hide");
        };

        setInterval(hide_and_display, 1000);
    });
};
loopImages();
```